# SSH key failure while git clone

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

Trying to clone my project from **Bitbucket** by using command `git clone`.

Before that I have created SSH key pair in Bitbucket I have placed public one in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in my pc that is trying to clone project. I also performed commands:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After executing `git clone` I got error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/g/projects/mypro/.git/
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to clone project from **Bitbucket**?

Comment: The public key must stay in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on a remote computer where you want to log in. It doesn't help if you put it on your computer because BitBucket doesn't connect to it. It's the other way around: you use your private part of the key to authenticate to BitBucket and the public part of your key must already be on the Bitbucket servers (uploaded through the web interface).

Comment: You can add you public key to your account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the public key from your local machine (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` by default) to the "SSH keys" section in your BitBucket account.

See the [BitBucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) for more information.